# How do I translate this GROUP BY / MIN SQL query into LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, translate

I plan on using this in a subquery but can't figure out the correct syntax to translate the following query into LINQ:

```
select ChapterID, min(MeetingDate)
from ChapterMeeting
group by ChapterID
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
var query = myDataContext.ChapterMeeting
  .GroupBy(cm => cm.ChapterID)
  .Select(g => new {
      g.Key,
      MinMeetingDate = g.Min(cm => cm.MeetingDate)
  });
```

Answer (score 16):

Well, Amy beat me to it, but in case you wanted to see it with the "comprehension" syntax:

```
var q = (
    from cm in context.ChapterMeeting
    group cm by cm.ChapterID into cmg
    select new {
        ChapterID = cmg.Key,
        FirstMeetingDate = cmg.Min(cm => cm.MeetingDate)});
```

Comment: Could you make a change edit to your answer (to "group cm by cm.ChapterID into cmg")? I can't make an edit yet :)