# convert SQL to LINQ group by min, count

Tags: linq

How convert SQL to LINQ

```
SELECT 
          [good_id]
          ,MIN([good_price]) as minPrice
          ,Count([distributor_id]) as distrCount
      FROM [Provizor].[dbo].[PRICES] where region_id=22
      GROUP BY [good_id]
      ORDER BY distrCount desc
```

How to do this in LINQ grouping

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654285/how-do-i-translate-this-group-by-min-sql-query-into-linq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var query = dbo.Prices
               .Where(x => x.region_id == 22)
               .GroupBy(x => x.good_id)
               .Select(g => new 
                { 
                   minPrice = g.Min(x => x.good_price), 
                   distrCount = g.Count(x=> x.distributor_id!=null)
                }
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.distrCount);
```

Comment: LINQ

    var price = (from p in _db.PRICEs
                             where p.region_id == 22
                             group p by p.good_id into g
                             select new { 
                                  good_id = g.Key
                                 ,minPrice = g.Min(x => x.good_price)
                                 , distrCount = g.Count(x => x.distributor_id != null) 
                             }
                 ).OrderByDescending(x => x.distrCount);